# How to read sub-string from a string and replace sub-string with a new value

Tags: coldfusion

Currently I am trying to read a sub-string from string and replace the sub-string with a new value.

```
<cfoutput>

<cfsavecontent variable="pckEmailContent">

    <p><a href="#TestURL#">Click here</a> to be directed to the assessment.</p>

</cfsavecontent>

</cfoutput>

<cfif findNoCase("TestLink", "#emailContent#", [start]) eq 1>

    <cfset  TestLink= pckEmailContent />

 </cfif>
```

Comment: <cfif findNoCase("TestLink", "#emailContent#", [start]) eq 1>
     
 <cfset  TestLink= pckEmailContent />      
</cfif> i was trying this

Comment: Can you please give more details? What you want to replace?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is neither a variable called "`emailContent`" nor is there the string "`TestLink`" inside since the latter is a variable whose contents will be in that place instead. Furthermore, you don't have to pass the variable wrapped in `"` and `#` to `findNoCase()` since you just want to pass but not output it there.